# Extension cord out of electric box for toilet seat bidet

Tags: electrical, bathroom, receptacle

I'm buying a new apartment and I cannot easily modify the walls to add an additional electrical box. There's only one outlet and it's by the mirror over the vanity.

I want to install an electric toilet seat bidet but I don't want the aesthetic of the cord or loss of use of one of 2 outlets for this semi-permanent installation.

Is there a way to wire up a narrow extension cord to come out of the electrical box and straight down to the ground where I can plug in the bidet?

EDIT:
Would it be a bad idea to build another GFCI box and route the cords together down the wall to this box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply use a flexible cord wherever you please (Code NEC 400.8)  *particularly* where fixed wiring in the walls would normally be used.

However, one type of allowable fixed wiring is a surface conduit such as Legrand Wiremold.

The "starter" box sits on the surface over your existing receptacle, and the surface conduit extends off its side, down the wall to wherever you need to go for the other outlet.

If you also want *more* receptacles, add that to the surface conduit system. You can go 3" to another receptacle before you head to wherever you're going.

You will absolutely need GFCI protection on something like a bidet, and the "starter" box will give you lots of room to mount a GFCI+receptacle combo device.   You can feed the bidet any other outlets from the GFCI+receptacle module, so they will also be GFCI protected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you happen to have a link to an example adapter box from Legrand, all of the options listed there seem for more corporate and I didn't see any GFCI ones from them. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant **starter** box like [Wiremold starter box](https://amzn.to/2qPseRv) -- and then mount in it a [GFCI+receptacle combo device](https://amzn.to/2HPLu9y) of any brand.